# How to sent code 200 and 403 with rest api and php

Tags: php, json, rest, restful-url

I developing a small crud application with php and restful api. I want to sent the code 200 if  a record is created and code 403 for error msgs. Below is my code:

```
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$age = $_POST['age'];

$query = $restObj->create_record($firstname,$lastname,$age);
echo json_encode([
      "message" => $query ? "User Created" : "Error creating user"
]);
```

This is my function for creating record:

```
public function create_record($firstname,$lastname,$age)
{   
$sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (firstname,lastname,age) VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$age')";
$query = mysqli_query($this->conn,$sql);    
return $query;  
}
```

The code works fine and I can create record but I don't know how to display code 200 and code 403 messages. Please Help

Comment: Your code is wide open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `http_response_code(200)`  to get and set the HTTP response code.

Refer to [PHP Manual: http-response-code](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php)

Comment: Can you please re-write the code as it will be really helpful. thanks